# How can I use a chrome browser action to load a webpage in the active tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want an extension to load a webpage when I click on it's browser action, and for various reasons including the need to have an icon, I am using a background script.
Here is my current broken code. I can read tab.url and access the current page, but I cannot change it and load a new one. I have spent hours searching for an answer, to no avail. Closest I got was someone implying that they were able to do this within a content script, but not how that would be done. I was hoping to avoid having multiple scripts. Can this be done in background.js and if so, how? If not, how can this be done in a content script, given that myURL is determined by background.js?

**On a final note: for this to be useful it MUST be loaded within the active tab. I do not want to create a new tab, a popup, or an iframe.**

background.js:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    tab.url = myURL;             // doesn't work!
    chrome.tabs.reload(tab.tabId);      // reload the page
    console.log("loading.. "+tab.url);
    });

{
```

manifest.json:

```
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "GTFO",
  "description": "Escape out of this domain and return to the last domain you've visited",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
          "activeTab","webNavigation","tabs"
        ],
    "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really should read [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-update), it's a very basic question.

```
chrome.tabs.update({url: myURL});
```